# Kafka services aren't coming up

Tags: apache-kafka, linux-kernel, rhel7, selinux

When I start the kafka services on my rhel machine,it fails & prints the following error.Nothing printed in logs aswell.

**[root@node01 java]#** systemctl start kafka

Job for kafka.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status kafka.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

*I have cross verified these kafka configurations files to that of another machine with similar setup.It all looks fine.Also checked few online resources & nothing much turned out to be helpful*.

Any thoughts?

**Output of journalctl -xe are as follows:**

```
-- Unit kafka.service has begun starting up.
May 28 15:30:09 hostm01 runuser[30740]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ossadm by (uid=0)
May 28 15:30:09 hostm01 runuser[30740]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user ossadm
May 28 15:30:09 hostm01 kafka[30733]: Starting kafka ... [  OK  ]
May 28 15:30:11 hostm01 kafka[30733]: [  OK  ]
May 28 15:30:11 hostm01 systemd[1]: Started Apache Kafka.
-- Subject: Unit kafka.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit kafka.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
May 28 15:30:11 hostm01 systemd[1]: kafka.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 28 15:30:12 hostm01 runuser[31178]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ossadm by (uid=0)
May 28 15:30:12 hostm01 kafka[31171]: Stopping kafka ... STOPPED
May 28 15:30:12 hostm01 runuser[31178]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user ossadm
May 28 15:30:12 hostm01 kafka[31171]: [17B blob data]
May 28 15:30:12 hostm01 systemd[1]: Unit kafka.service entered failed state.
May 28 15:30:12 hostm01 systemd[1]: kafka.service failed.
```

Comment: Can you please include the output of "journalctl -xe" in the question details?

Comment: @MeghVidani added them.

Comment: Okay. Can you also check the logs and post the error portion (almost 20 lines preceding the error, the error itself and 10 lines after that) in a code block with this question? I'm suspecting that this maybe an OutOfMemoryError. In which case, we need to see what other processes are consuming the memory. what is the RAM of the server you're running this on? Also, are you running any other heavy Java processes on the same server(Hadoop Namenode, Zookeeper, etc.)?